# URL showing full path by default: Angular UI-Router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Today is my first day working with Angular and I am just starting to use ui-router. The [demos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QETUuZ27N0w) that I have been watching suggest that angular would default the URL to something like `192.168.1.1/#/`, but mine is showing the full path. **What could I be doing (or not doing) to cause this?** I'm not sure what information to provide, so comment to request more information

Here is my App module so far:

```
angular
  .module('app', [
    'ui.router'
   ])
  .config(['$urlRouterProvider', '$stateProvider', function($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider){
      $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
   }])
```

Note: I am hosting my web-app on a NAS device that acts as a web-server.

Comment: It seems like you might have some terminology confusion here, but it's hard to know for sure without a bit more code.  What do you mean by "full path"? (that could have a few different interpretations).

Comment: @Claies So the address bar reads "http://##.###.140.70/code/Fitness_Analytics/Version_4/index.html". In the examples the path showed "192.168.1.1:9000/#/"

Comment: that has to do with how your web server is configured.  Angular is only concerned with the portion *after* the `index.html` or `#/`.  It actually doesn't sound like your NAS is actually a web server, it is merely allowing you to view the files saved on it.

Comment: I see. So I need to move the files up next to the 'code' directory?

Comment: unless you can configure a virtual directory in your NAS to point to the root of the angular app, moving the root of the angular app downward is your only option.  However, that is really more of a question for people that know something about your NAS device.